# exception thrown when creating an array c++

Tags: c++

Im basically generating a array for a flat plane in my game using this algorithm, but I couldn't get it to work as there is a exception when I run the program. (GLuint is just unsigned int in opengl)

```
const GLuint planeDimension = 30.0f;
const GLuint half = planeDimension / 2;
const GLuint verticesCount = planeDimension * planeDimension;
int counter = 0;
GLfloat planeVertices[verticesCount];

for (GLuint length = 0; length < planeDimension; length++) {
    for (GLuint width = 0; width < planeDimension; width++) {
        planeVertices[counter++] = length - half;
        planeVertices[counter++] = 0.0f;
        planeVertices[counter++] = width - half;
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of all you call 3 times counter incrementation. That is 2 too many. Your array is just 3 times too small for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing outside the array in your loop. Your loop has as one iteration for each element in `planeVertices`. But you're incrementing `counter` 3 times each time through the loop. So about 1/3 of the way through all the loops `counter` will reach the end of the array, then you'll start writing outside the array, which causes undefined behavior.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Why are you writing 3 different elements of the array each time through the loop? So it's not clear how to fix it. You could simply declare it 3 times as large:

```
GLfloat planeVertices[verticesCount * 3];
```

Or you could declare it as a 2-dimensional array:

```
GLfloat planeVertices[verticesCount][3];
```

Then your loop would do:

```
planeVertices[counter][0] = length - half;
planeVertices[counter][1] = 0.0f;
planeVertices[counter][2] = width - half;
counter++;
```